# Issues using result from LINQ query, in other LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to select elements from a table, based on a foreign key in another table. My code looks like this:

```c#
var account = await _context.Accounts.FirstAsync(a => a.Id == new Guid(id) && a.UserId == new Guid(user.Id));
if (account == null) return NotFound();

var detaillines = await _context.DetailLines.Where(d => new Guid(d.Account) == account.Id).ToListAsync();
```

It is failing with the error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(d => new Guid(d.Account) == __account_Id_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
> ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

How come I am not able to use the ID from the account I have in the first query, in the second query?

UPDATE:

The following change to the 2nd LINQ query solved it:

```
var detailLinesForAccount = _context.DetailLines
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(d => new Guid(d.Account) == account.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Try `var someId = new Guid(id); var userId = new Guid(user.id);` and then use `someId` and `userId` in your `FirstAsync()` query. Do the same thing for the `Where()` query and see if you still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `new Guid(...)` cannot be translated. Try use this code for first part:

```
var guide = new Guid(id);
var userGuid = new Guid(user.Id);

var account = await _context.Accounts.FirstAsync(a => a.Id == guide && a.UserId == userGuid);
if (account == null) return NotFound();
```

But for the second part, you must use client evaluation or change design or logic.
For client evaluation:

```
var detaillines = await _context.DetailLines
    .AsEnumerable().Where(d => new Guid(d.Account) == account.Id).ToListAsync();
```

Be careful when using client evaluation and consider *Potential memory leak* and so on.

**More detail:**

> **Client evaluation:** If the top-level projection in the query can't be translated to the server (Provider has no insight into how the method is implemented), EF Core will fetch any required data from the server and evaluate the remaining parts of the query on the client.(All the data needs to be pulled into memory to apply the filter on the client.)